# Google Tag Manager - Form Trigger Firing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I created a GTM tag / trigger for form submit as follows:

**Tag:**

- Track Type: Event
- Category: FormSubmissions
- Action: Submit
- Label: AskForAQuote

--

**Triggering:**

- Trigger Type: Form Submission
- Wait for Tags: true
- Check Validation: true
- Enable this trigger when: Page URL == X
- This trigger fires on:  Page URL == X

I then setup a goal to treat a conversion to occur when I receive:

Goal Details:
Category == FormSubmissions, Action == Submit, Label == AskForAQuote

So it is working and I do see goals converting when I submit the form, but I was curious about something:

When I enter preview mode (which pulls up the special preview GTM pane where you can see the activity) the trigger says it fired. My preconditions are simply that the page url == X as you see above.

Does that just mean the preconditions "fired" in the sense it's valid? Or does it mean it actually tracked a goal. I'd have to assume a basic GTM form SUBMIT trigger fires when the actual html form is SUBMITTED, not when you arrive on a page.

Is this me being paranoid, or is something wrong? Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also using the Facebook pixel on your site? I had the same problem and it turns out that the FB pixel code always triggers a gtm.formsubmit call.

Just add: Form URL - does not contain facebook.com/tr in your trigger.